# Non-nullable field warning when initializing field inside a method that is called inside constructor (CS8618)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0

Compiler does not "see" that non-nullable field is initialized inside an constructor because field is initialized inside a method that is called inside constructor. I turned on switch for warnings to become errors in project. Why is that?

Code example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private List<ColumnWidth> ColumnsWidth;
    public TestClass()
    {
       InitDrawingProcess();
    }

    private void InitDrawingProcess()
    {
       ColumnsWidth = GetRowColumnsWidth(X);
    }

    private List<ColumnWidth> GetRowColumnsWidth(double x)
    {
        var columnsPositions = new List<ColumnWidth>();
        foreach (var widthPct in TableDesign.ColumnsWidth)
        {
            var width = Width * widthPct;
            columnsPositions.Add(new ColumnWidth { X = x, Width = width });
            x += width;
        }

        return columnsPositions;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is `GetRowColumnsWidth`?

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn edited the question. Butchered the code a bit. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the nullable analysis is not deep enough to detect this condition.

However, you can inform the compiler that `InitDrawingProcess()` does initialise the field by decorating it with the [`MemberNotNull` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullattribute?view=net-7.0) like so:

```
[MemberNotNull(nameof(ColumnsWidth))]
private void InitDrawingProcess()
{
    ColumnsWidth = GetRowColumnsWidth(X);
}
```

This requires .NET 5 or later - you're using .NET 6 so it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to the approach suggested by Matthew Watson is declare it as follows, which informs the compiler that the member is initialized in other code:

```
private List<ColumnWidth> ColumnsWidth = null!;
```

Comment: That's fraught with peril though - if you add another constructor that doesn't initialise the field you won't get any warning.